# AS3: How to make movieclip appear on middle of a separate mc container?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I've been searching and having trouble doing this the right way.So my player has 2 arms which are joined in one mc. Now I'm trying to make the body(which is doesn't belong on the container mc) go between them, so it's like R arm first then body then L arm. The 2 arms rotate on mouse direction, i don't want the body too. Any ideas what way I should go?

EDIT:
please see my sample image
[image]

The checked thing is the result I'm looking for. But since the 2 arms is combined on one MC, I can't make the body appear on the middle between the 2 arms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your nesting model like this:

[image]

And then store your arms in an Array or a Vector, and change every arm's rotation separately.
It's the only way

Comment: Oh my, THAT between ))

Comment: Oh, that's the one I'm recently done. Oh well, if that's the only way to do it, so be it. Thanks.